# Django Rest API filter keeper query (foreignkey)

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Django Rest API has user input in foreignkey format. The User input returns all users. But I only want to fetch users that are in the unit of the requesting user.

current keeper select input:

```
queryset = User.objects.all()
```

my wish keeper input:

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(unit=request.user.unit)
```

serializers.py:

```
class InventorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
  fields = ('keeper','status','name')
```

views.py:

```
class InventoryGet(generics..RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = InventorySerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    lookup_field = 'id'
    queryset = Inventory.objects.all()
```

models.py

```
keeper = models.ForeignKey(User,models.SET_NULL,null=true,blank=true)
status =  models.CharField(max_length=500)
name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

Answer (score 0):

To include a custom queryset you can override the `get_queryset()` method like this. For further reading of what methods and properties are available you can have a look at this [link](https://www.cdrf.co/3.13/rest_framework.generics/RetrieveUpdateAPIView.html), or the [official docs.](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview)

```py
    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.filter(unit=self.request.user.unit)
```

In case your desired query didn't work please share your full `models.py` file. As of right now, that is unclear to me.

Comment: No,I will change select input, keeper foreignkey. I'm not change return queryset in API. 


The rest of my models.py file is color, size etc. such as trivial variables.